# Uploading image Laravel

Tags: laravel, file, upload

I try to upload file inside my `/public/images/profils` directory but, i don't know why, it's not working !

this is my controller function :

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        if ($request->file('image')->isValid()) {
            
            $validated = $request->validate([
                'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png|max:2000',
            ]);
            $extension = $request->file('image')->extension();
            $name = uniqid('img_');
            $request->file('image')->storeAs('/public/images/profils', $name.'.'.$extension);
        }
    }
```

When i check on the folder, no file are created but no error appears on website. I add that the image is sent from the form and passes the validation

someone have the answer ?
Thanks !

Comment: Hi Devix and welcome to stackoverflow. Your post is not detailed enough and here's how you could improve it: 
By displaying the file containing the list of your application's disks
A DD of your request POST

Comment: The general approach should be uploading to `storage/app/public/images/profils`, then symlink your `storage/app/public` to `public` via `php artisan storage:link`: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Have a look at `File Storage` section clicking: [click here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem).
This section will cover what you really need for uploading an image/file.
Remember to post detailed question with block codes and details for each block code, and what you've tried so far. Happy coding!

Comment: please check with `mimes:jpg` instead of `mimes:jpeg` and make sure to run the `php artisan storage:link` before to use the storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all laravel has 2 directory for assets:

- /public : for public assets
- /storage/app : for storing private assets

if you want to save a file with `$file->store` it gets a **relative** path from you based on `/storage/app`

if you want to make the asset public, you have to make a symlink like this:

```
/storage/app/public --> /public/storage
```

with this symlink you can access a public directory within /storage/app/ for example:

```
$file = $request->file("file");
$address = $file->store("public/tmp_pic");
```

and you can access it by a public url later.

```
//your public URL will start from public directory
// and because of symlink you have to add /storage
$uri =  "/storage".substr($address, 6);
```

you can add a symlink by laravel artisan command like this:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

or add it manually